# Drawing colourful box in a A4 page

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

I am writting my masters thesis. I want to put 2x2 block boxes in some pages. For example:

[image]

I can add as image but I do not want to do that. I can draw box using tcolorbox using the following code:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My Heading]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

But the problem is how can I put box as 2x2 format? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: See the tcolorbox documentation library "raster".

Comment: For this kind of boxes look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262171/1952 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232120/1952

Answer (score 3):

By default `tcolorbox` declares all boxes with `width=\linewidth`, so if you want more than one box on same line, you'll have to adjust their width. But this is not enough, because, also by default a `tcolorbox` also starts a new paragraph, so you also need to fix options `before` and `after` or use something like `nobeforeafter`.

If instead of environment `tcolorbox` you use command `\tcbox`, box width is automatically adjusted to box contents and they don't start a new paragraph.

Examples for `tcbox` start at page 13 in `tcolorbox` documentation. And first example with several `tcolorbox` environment on same line in page 17.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My Heading, width=.45\linewidth, nobeforeafter]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\hfill
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My Heading, width=.45\linewidth, nobeforeafter]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My Heading, width=.45\linewidth, nobeforeafter]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\hfill
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My Heading, width=.45\linewidth, nobeforeafter]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]